# New to angular, cant wrap my head around accessing variables from outside of a component

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, angular7

Ok, let me try to summarize as well as possible. I am new to Angular, have searched pretty thoroughly, but cant seem to find the answer to my issue:

Right now I have:
**Api.Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

export class TokenService {
  private tokenUrl = 'http://urlofapi/auth/token';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  addToken(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.tokenUrl, httpOptions);
  }

}
```

**api.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TokenService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api',
  templateUrl: './api.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api.component.scss']
})

export class ApiComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tokenService.addToken().subscribe((data => {
      this.data = data;
      const finalToken = this.data['token'];

      console.log(finalToken);
    });

  }
}
```

The token is being returned from the API via the POST handshake. It is being returned in the format:

```
{
  "token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJVVUlEIjoiYTM3YWFmNzAtZjU0Yy00MGMwLWEwZGUtOTE4NTBkNjY1ODI2IiwiZGV2aWNlSWQiOiIxMjIzMzMiLCJleHBpcmVzQXQiOiIyMDE4LTExLTI5VDIwOjI4OjM3WiJ9.VcTt_TJWFA58iBCDS0JnTAJkH9EzU15QES9k0vI84Ic"
}
```

I am logging the token to the console, so I know it is defining and receiving it.

**So My issue**
I am getting the token, it is being set as finalToken, it is being logged to the console. The issue is that for some reason that variable is not visible to any of the rest of the app

so if I try to call it from anywhere outside of the ngOnInit(){} wrapper, it comes back as undefined.

For instance, if I want to print it to screen in my api.component.html by using:

{{ finalToken }}

in browser, I get:

```
<p _ngcontent-c1=""></p>
```

with no errors, but it is not pulling the variable

So VERY tl:dr; is it possible to make the const finalToken available globally? I will need to be able to submit it in the header of any additional requests to the API, but right now I cant even access it in the HTML of the component it lives in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to make it globally accessible as a variable - leave it in the service and inject it where you want it (as you are already doing). This will allow for better data encapsulation down the track.

To get it accessible in the component html you need to create a `public` property for it. So instead of:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tokenService.addToken().subscribe((data => {
      this.data = data;
      const finalToken = this.data['token'];

      console.log(finalToken);
    });

  }
```

Do this:

```
public finalToken: string = null;
ngOnInit() {
    this.tokenService.addToken().subscribe((data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.finalToken = this.data['token'];

      console.log(finalToken);
    });

  }
```

Your html `{{ finalToken }}` does not need to change.

Comment: You rock!!! I was completely lost on the public portion. This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielStockbridge Glad I could help, you were pretty damn close.

Comment: Unfortunately "pretty damn close" had me banging my head against the wall for far too long. Kicking myself for not just spinning up a stack overflow account sooner and asking